# AppCode no product for target

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, simulator, appcode

I am trying to run Swift iOS app in iPad simulator in AppCode. App is successfully built, but there is an error

```
Error running ios-app: No product for target 'ios-app'
```

I am quite green in iOS development and I am trying to switch from XCode to AppCode since I am more familiar with it.

I am using latest AppCode (3.1.7), everything works great in XCode.

Thanks for responses :)

Comment: have you installed a beta XCode 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem - I wasn't able to run my XCTest unit tests in AppCode any more although they were running perfectly in XCode.

My error message was "No product for target ..."

I was able to get them running again by switching to the latest AppCode 3.2 build (Tascalate).

You can get this one by opening the IDE Preferences, then go to Appearence & Behavior > System Settings > Updates

There you can switch to the Early Access Program to check for updates.

Hope this solves your issue, too.

**Edit:** Since Julian above asked an important question about the XCode version... in my case I was using AppCode 3.1.7 and XCode 7 beta 4. The switch to AppCode 3.2 EAP - as already mentioned above - solved the issue.

Comment: Yepp I'm running a newer XCode then AppCode. They where out of sync. Downgrading to a version of XCode who is supported fixed it

Answer (score -1):

I have delete the .idea folder and restart Appcode, it's work

Comment: This worked an absolute treat for me. You just lose some project-specific ide configuration. Keep a backup of the folder if you need.